# Magento 2: how endpoints (REST) to get data from database

Tags: magento2, api, shipping-methods, rest-api

How endpoints `<host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-method`
to get data from a database or mention function or class that helps this API to get data from the database?

Because I am so confused about how this API to get data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific endpoint you have named you can find this under `vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml`.

```
    <route url="/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface" method="estimateByExtendedAddress"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
```

Here you see:

1. The route url which will be matched,
2. The class that will be called, in this case the interface `Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface`,
3. The method that will be called, `estimateByExtendedAddress`

Assuming you do not have any custom modules with a preference for `Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface` this will be using `\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByExtendedAddress`